# Why are type instances (a->a) and (a->a->a) conflicting in GHC 7.8?

Tags: haskell, type-families

The `hmatrix` package contains the following type families code:

```
type family BoundsOf x

type instance BoundsOf (a->a) = Int
type instance BoundsOf (a->a->a) = (Int,Int)
```

On GHC 7.6, this compiles fine.

On GHC 7.7 (leading to 7.8), we get:

```
lib/Numeric/ContainerBoot.hs:515:15:
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      BoundsOf (a -> a) -- Defined at lib/Numeric/ContainerBoot.hs:515:15
      BoundsOf (a -> a -> a)
        -- Defined at lib/Numeric/ContainerBoot.hs:516:15
```

What kind of "conflict" is meant here? I cannot see the problem with these instances.

---

**Update:** Here is a minimal example `Test.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Test where

type family BoundsOf x

type instance BoundsOf (a->a) = Int
type instance BoundsOf (a->a->a) = (Int,Int)
```

Trying that:

```
ghci Test.hs       # 7.6, all fine
ghci-7.7 Test.hs   # fails
```

Comment: http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8154

Comment: Sure looks like a bug.

Comment: A good explanation of why this shouldn't work has been added to that GHC ticket by someone called goldfire.

Comment: I can see an understand goldfire's comment, but I find it disturbing.  The types `(a->a)` and `(a->a->a)` cannot be the same for any finite instanciation of `a`.  So it should be fine.  But it isn't, which means that infinite types must have snuck in to ghc.

Comment: @augustss If I interpret the comment right, then you can write `type instance Family (OthertypeFamily a)`, and since `OtherTypeFamily` is not a type constructor but just a type function, it's possible that `TyFun a a = TyFun a (TyFun a)`. The problem would then be that the code parsing `type instance Family (T a b)` doesn't know whether `T` is a type constructor or a type family. I don't know whether it's a good idea to be able to use type families for other family instances, but somebody seems to think it is

Comment: Did you ever get hmatrix to compile on 7.8? I am on 7.8.1 RC1 and I am still seeing this.

Comment: @stevejb Maybe you can try building it from `master`? [This merged commit](https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/commit/70c4b197cc7cea6bf6c162205bb439a9cb80a2ff) seems to claim fixing the build with 7.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akio Takano managed to construct an example program that in GHC 7.6 coerces `Int` to `IO String` using the type family declaration

```
type family F a
type instance F (a -> a) = Int
type instance F (a -> a -> a) = IO String
```

See http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8162 or https://github.com/takano-akio/type-family-overlap.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks more like a bug in GHC 7.6 TBH.

If you remove the syntax sugar for function types, what you have is

```
type instance BoundsOf (((->) a) a) = Int
type instance BoundsOf (((->) a) (((->) a) a)) = (Int, Int)
```

which looks conflicting...

Now, if I try to pull this same trick with another type constructor instead of `((->) a)`, I get an error from GHC 7.6 as well:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
type family BoundsOf x

type instance BoundsOf (Maybe a) = Int
type instance BoundsOf (Maybe (Maybe a)) = (Int, Int)
```

Which results in:

```
tyfams.hs:4:15:
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      type instance BoundsOf (Maybe a) -- Defined at tyfams.hs:4:15
      type instance BoundsOf (Maybe (Maybe a)) -- Defined at tyfams.hs:5:15
```

I don't see why it should work for `((->) a)`.

Comment: It only conflicts if you have infinite types (if `a ~ a->a`).  The proper comparison would be with a type that have two type variables like `Either`, not `Maybe`.  With `Either a a` and `Either a (Either a a)`  you can clearly unify `Either a a ~ a` only if you have infinite types.